# Visual Studio warning C4596 in constructor declaration

Tags: visual-c++

Warning C4596 can, apparently, be solicited by several configuration.  I found a few that did not match my problem so this is submited:

```
class dialog_base : public wxFrame
{

public:
   dialog_base::dialog_base( const wxString& title );
… }
```

> 1>    E:\WX\wx_numbers_01\dialog_base.h(18,28): warning C4596: '{ctor}': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file wx_numbers.cpp)

So how should this constructor be declared?

Just in case, as I read the error it comes from this part of the declaration:
dialog_base::dialog_base

Comment: Which of these lines is line 18?

Comment: Just declare the constructor as `public: dialog_base(const wxString& title);`.  In the actual implementation, you would write `dialog_base::dialog_base(const wxString& title) { /* implementation goes here */ }`

Comment: I recall learning it that way, but have not done much class work recently.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I realize removing the "unexpected qualification" will resolve this warning. In your case, just use

```
dialog_base( const wxString& title );
```

May I know the reason why one would want to use

```
dialog_base::dialog_base( const wxString& title );
```